# Partial derivative on vector elements with the vector itself

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I have a function $F: \mathbb R $ X $\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$, $F(x,y)= \begin{bmatrix} 3x+y_1-cosy_1+e^{y_2} \\ e^x-x+y_1-y_2-1 \end{bmatrix}$. I want to get $DF$ for this function. I thought it would be a $2x2$ matrix like this:\begin{bmatrix} 3 & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} (3x+y_1-cosy_1+e^{y_2}) \\ e^x-1 & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(e^x-x+y_1-y_2-1) \end{bmatrix}
But then I don't know how to get the partial derivative respect to $y$ with $y_1, y_2$ in the function. Does anyone know how to do this partial differentiation?

Comment: If you view it as a function from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, you'll get a $2 \times 3$ matrix.

Comment: You can also remove the x terms from the $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ equation to isolate the partial derivatives part that's unknown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\tfrac{\partial ~~~}{\partial\vec y}$ is itself a gradient operator, $\nabla_{y_1,y_2}$, and the gradient of a scalar with respect to a 2D vector is a $1\times 2$ matrix (a row vector).  So just nest the operations.

$$\begin{align}\nabla_{x,\vec y}~\vec F(x,\vec y)&=\left(\begin{bmatrix}\tfrac{\partial ~~}{\partial x}\\\nabla_{\vec y}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}F_1(x,\vec y)&F_2(x,\vec y)\end{bmatrix}\right)^{\top}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}\tfrac{\partial~~}{\partial x} F_1(x,y)&\nabla_{y_1,y_2}F_1(x,\vec y)\\\tfrac{\partial~~}{\partial x} F_2(x,y)&\nabla_{y_1,y_2}F_2(x,\vec y)\end{bmatrix}\\[1ex]&=\begin{bmatrix}\tfrac{\partial~~}{\partial x} F_1(x,y)&\begin{bmatrix}\tfrac{\partial~~~}{\partial y_1}F_1(x,\vec y)&\tfrac{\partial~~~}{\partial y_2}F_1(x,\vec y)\end{bmatrix}\\\tfrac{\partial~~}{\partial x} F_2(x,y)&\begin{bmatrix}\tfrac{\partial~~~}{\partial y_1}F_2(x,\vec y)&\tfrac{\partial~~~}{\partial y_2}F_2(x,\vec y)\end{bmatrix}\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$

---

This nesting might be ignored by some.  If we define the composition: $\vec G(x,y_1,y_2)=\vec F(x,\vec y)$ , and *handwave* the gradient operators as being equivalent, then we would claim $\nabla_{x,\vec y}\vec F(x,\vec y)=\nabla_{x,y_1,y_2}\vec G(x,y_1,y_2)$, which is a $2{\times}3$ matrix.

---

Either way, you can evaluate the six members.